# window.open why some user's IE open new window every time.

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This issue is driving me crazy, I have an app which is referenced via .asp pages and in one of these pages there is a javascript function to open a popup

`window.open("popup.aspx", "myPopup","width=300,height=100,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,alwaysLowered=yes,location=no,directories=no,titlebar=no");`

Looking up various documentation it has been stated that if the same window name is used then this window will be re-used. This is correct on most user's IE but on an some end users PC it opens an additional popup window even though the same code is being used.

To verify this I created a test.aspx and simply duplicated the open function previously stated. On my PC I got one popup window, on the some users got two. It’s definitely Internet Explorer on this PC because I have installed Firefox and there is no issue and the same window is referenced. 
IE(11) version is same all.

What problem??

Comment: Not an answer you'll be happy with, but IE is notorious for straying from HTML standards. Your users seeing the duplicate popup windows are likely on older versions of IE (i.e., 6 or 7 or lower). Are these users on Windows XP? If so, they could easily be running IE 6, but the highest version of IE they can run on XP is IE 8.

Comment: Trouble with user's os is win7 and IE(11.0.15). My enviroment is same, but no problem.

Comment: Well, my guess is those few users have a setting in IE that most don't. Under Internet Options > Tabs, there are some settings about always opening in a new window. They likely have that option checked.

Comment: thanks but we tried all option and restored IE congif origin. But T.T

Answer (score 0):

Save an object reference of the opened window to a global variable and do a validation before calling window.open:

```
var windowObjRef = null; // global variable

if(windowObjRef== null || windowObjRef.closed)
{
   windowObjRef = window.open("popup.aspx", "myPopup","width=300,height=100,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,alwaysLowered=yes,location=no,directories=no,titlebar=no");
}
else
{
  windowObjRef.focus();
}
```

Comment: thanks  but this popup called other pages, so variable set null. So new open same popup.